# Converting feature to raster, missing values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, features, values

I have converted many features from the same shapefile to rasters, but am now getting an issue where values are missing. Converting the percentage values in column a212 (data type long) produces a raster with only 0, even though this feature has several rows with non-0 values. There are only 18 rows out of ~2.4 million with values higher than 0, but that shouldn't matter?

Having a similar issue with next column a213, where there are even more values >0, but is producing a raster with only 0 and 36?[image]

See screenshot

Comment: percentages, so just numbers between 0-100.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: type is long and number form is numeric

Comment: Could your pixel size be much larger than for example the feature in the shapefile with a212 value of 67?

Comment: Thanks BERA. I don't think that's the problem as the statistics in the source tab of layer properties shows 0 for min, max, mean, Std dev and classes.